# Angular template compilation TS2531 error with a non-null value

Tags: angular, typescript

With `"strictNullChecks": true` in `tsconfig.json`, when I test a synchronous value subscribing to an initialized Observable with an async pipe, I get a TS2531 error (Object is possibly 'null') :

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable, of} from 'rxjs';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `
        <div *ngIf="(test$|async) === 0">Zero</div>
        <div *ngIf="(test$|async) > 0">Positive</div>
    `,
    styles: []
})
export class AppComponent {
    test$: Observable<number> = of<number>(1);
}
```

[Compilation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nf3zA.png)

Does someone understand why?

Comment: With Observable, it will determine result may be null. It same with you call API and some case API return null value.

Comment: @HienNguyen observables can have definite non nullable types. the async pipe is what can possibly return null.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

this is introduced by angular 9's full template type checks being combined with strict null checks and the async pipe.  basically, the async pipe assumes an observable will be asynchronous, and if it is, it emits null in the meantime.  So the result of the async pipe CAN be null, even though you know it won't be in this case.

so, it's not saying `test$` could be null, it's saying the result of `(test$ | async)` could be null, and strict null checks means you can't compare null to a number with `>` or `<` operators which is why only those (and the or equal variants) throw the error at you.

you can tell it to shut up with the non null assertion operator:

```
<div *ngIf="(test$|async)! > 0">Positive</div>
```

or you can make use of the new `$any` template cast function to disable type checking:

```
<div *ngIf="$any(test$|async) > 0">Positive</div>
```

or if you wish, you can disable template type checking app wide by setting `fullTemplateTypeCheck` to false in your tsconfig angular compiler options

more here: https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#strict-null-checks

Comment: Thanks for this; it's a big help. Do you know why `<div *ngIf="(test$|async) && (test$|async) > 0">` does not work?

Comment: angular (and ts for that matter) is not able to infer the type safety of the result of a function in this way.... for instance if I had some variable `i: number | null`, and I had some function `const isNotNull = <T>(val: T) => val !== null && val` and I attempted to do `isNotNull(i) && isNotNull(i) > 0` this would also fail, whereas `i !== null && i > 0` would work fine. and pipes are just functions

Comment: Another approach is to specify an alternative to null using OR, e.g. `(test$ | async) || 0`

Answer (score 0):

(test$|async)

as you are applying an async pipe,chances there the test$ may be null that is why you are
getting the object is possibly null exception.

you can try this solution.

(test$ | async)? ===0

Refer the below link
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16982