# Convert Object to Array then display one element every few seconds

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-httpclient, angular-observable

I call an API in my service like so

```
getItems(): Observable<{}> {
    return this.http.get(<path>)
    .pipe(
      pluck('items'),
    );
  }
```

That returns data in this shape:

```
items: Object { key: value, key: value, key: value ...}
```

I subscribe to this in my component like so

```
items$!: any;
constructor(private readonly service: Service) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.getItems().subscribe(items => this.items$ = items);
  }
```

And display them in my template like so

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items$ | keyvalue">
    <mat-card>
        <mat-card-header>
          {{item.key}}
        </mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-content>
          {{item.value}}
        </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

However, what I would actually like is to loop through displaying these items one at a time every few seconds or so, as opposed to just displaying all of them at once. I would also like to only make one http call to accomplish this. I have looked around and found bits and pieces of what a solution could look like, however, it usually involves at least converting the object to an array and then perhaps using some sort of Subject to observe the original observable subscribed to? What could be a clean way of doing this? Thank you.

Comment: Do you want them all to be displayed at once, but slowly (like a slowly growing array). Or do you want to display one, then display the next, then the next (like a slide show)?

Comment: Like a slideshow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a stream that emits a value every 5 seconds and share the same value with all subscribers.

```js
item$: Observable<Item>;

ngOnInit(): void { 
  this.item$ = this.service.getItems().pipe(
    switchMap(items => zip(
      from(items),
      timer(0,5000)
    )),
    map(([x,_]) => x),
    share()
  );
}
```

Subscribe to the stream. Async pipe is the best way to do that with angular

```js
<div>
    <mat-card>
        <mat-card-header>
          {{(item$ | async).key}}
        </mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-content>
          {{(item$ | async).value}}
        </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

#### Update - Using a Custom Operator

```js
function intervalArray<T>(milliseconds = 1000): OperatorFunction<T[], T> {

  return s => s.pipe(
    concatMap((a: T[]) => zip(
      from(a),
      timer(0, milliseconds)
    ).pipe(
      map(([x,_]) => x)
    ))
  );
  
}

ngOnInit(): void { 
  this.item$ = this.service.getItems().pipe(
    intervalArray(5000),
    share()
  );
}
```

Comment: This looks good too, but it is resulting in an "object is possibly null" error for me in the template with the .key and .value

Comment: try `(item$ | async)?.key`  : A related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61420325/angular-template-compilation-ts2531-error-with-a-non-null-value

Comment: That is pretty much working except for whatever reason when you first navigate to the page, the first value doesn't work. But every 5 seconds thereafter it does what it's supposed to. I also get several of these errors ```ERROR TypeError: _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.\u0275\u0275pipeBind1(...) is null```

Comment: I'm not rly into angular, not my thing. Seems ngOnInit doesn't wait long enough. A simple answer is to try something like `timer(250,5000)`, but that's a code smell. the real answer is to figure out which of angular's callbacks best corresponds to the HTML being fully loaded, then sure `shareReplay(1)` instead of `share()` that or use `startWith(defaultValue)`

Comment: Thanks. Using shareReplay(1) resulted in the first value being displayed as well and it works perfectly after that as well. However, for some reason if you refresh it, well, only works occasionally.  When it doesn't work, I get the error that ```ERROR TypeError: can't convert undefined to object``` which emanates from my objectToArray method that I pass items to in that switch map (because items at the point is an object that I have to convert into an array). That's apparently not because it isn't destroyed- the async pipe takes care of unsubscribing from observables must be something else

Comment: Throw in a `tap(console.log)` before the `switchMap` to print out what gets sent to 'objectToArray' and see if they're different during a re-fresh. Not sure what's happening, but that's where I'd start looking.

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to convert the data from your API into an array which will have the following structure:

```
const apiData = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 }, { d: 4 }, { e: 5 }, { f: 6 }];
```

Next you can make use of the following code which uses [`bufferCount`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/bufferCount), [`concatMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/concatMap) and [`delay`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/delay) operators

```
data = [];

from(apiData)
  .pipe(
    bufferCount(1),
    concatMap(objs => of(objs).pipe(delay(3000)))
  )
  .subscribe(e => {
    this.data.push(e);
  });
```

and on the template

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data">
    {{item | json}}    <-- tweak around with it to get exact details you need -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this would probably work. However, how do you convert from object to array in this context? I had tried what's mentioned [here](https://www.cloudhadoop.com/2018/08/typescript-how-to-convert-object-to.html) but couldn't quite get it to work with the getItems() method.

Comment: You could do that using [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). An example, 
`var obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 };
    let test = [];
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
      test.push({ [key]: value })
    }`

Comment: I'm really struggling with this conversion here. I tried ```this.service.getItems().subscribe(items => this.items = this.objectToArray(items));``` where the objectToArray is the method in your comment. ```this.items``` is undefined after.

Comment: Figured out the conversion anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Nicholas, Mrk. You've been very helpful. I marked Mrk's answer as the answer since essentially I used their code. Just in case anyone was curious about what solved the few thing I mentioned in the comments and wanted to see the whole solution in context, here's what I did in its entirety

```
//in the service
getItems(): Observable<{}> {
    return this.http.get(<URL>)
    .pipe(
      pluck('items'),
    );
  }

//in the template, this change stopped the initial null issue I was having
<div *ngIf="item$ | async as state">
  <mat-card>
      <mat-card-header>
        {{state.currencyPair}}
      </mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-content>
        {{state.exchangeRate}}
      </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
</div>

//in the component
  item$!: Observable<Item>;
  constructor(private readonly service: Service) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.item$ = this.service.getItems().pipe(
      switchMap(items => zip(
        from(this.objectToArray(items)),
        timer(0,5000)
      )),
      map(([x,_]) => x),
      shareReplay(1)
    );
  }

  objectToArray(object: {}) {
    let items: Item[] = [];
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) { 
      items.push({ key : key, value : value })
    }
    return items;
  }

//item.ts
export interface Item {
    key: string;
    value: any;
}
```

The issue now where after refreshing the objectToArray gets an undefined object is apparently a problem with the API, as my free plan doesn't support https encryption lol. Which I thought I solved by taking the s out of the URL but *shrug*.

I'd actually be interested to see how your code would work in context, Nicholas, if you felt like sharing. In any case, I need to dive deeper into Angular libraries and learn more. Thanks!